# Using SASS to pass in a variable into a mixin where the declaration is a string

Tags: css, unicode, sass

I am building a SASS mixin that allows me to pass in various vars to build a font-awesome declaration like so:

```
@mixin after-font-awesome($unicode, $size, $margin, $color, $weight) {
  &:after {
    content:$unicode;
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    font-size:$size;
    color:$color;
    font-weight:$weight;
    margin:$margin;
    @content;
  }
}
```

the usage would be as such:

```
@include after-font-awesome('\f078', 15px, 0 0 0 0.3em, orange, 900) {}
```

which requires me to pass in the unicode with `'\XXX'` the single quotes and the slash as a string. this works, but i am trying to do the following where i pass in just the unicode numbers such as `f078`, and when it gets to the mixin it prints it as `'\f078'`. after reading some documentation i tried as such:

```
@mixin after-font-awesome($unicode, $size, $margin, $color, $weight) {
  &:after {
    content:'\#{$unicode}';
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    font-size:$size;
    color:$color;
    font-weight:$weight;
    margin:$margin;
    @content;
  }
}
```

or

```
@mixin after-font-awesome($unicode, $size, $margin, $color, $weight) {
  &:after {
    content:'\{$unicode}';
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    font-size:$size;
    color:$color;
    font-weight:$weight;
    margin:$margin;
    @content;
  }
}
```

or

```
@mixin after-font-awesome($unicode, $size, $margin, $color, $weight) {
  &:after {
    content:'\$unicode';
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    font-size:$size;
    color:$color;
    font-weight:$weight;
    margin:$margin;
    @content;
  }
}
```

but alas it did not work. any help would be appreciated in figuring this out with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my project.

```
$unicode: f0ca;
$withslash: "\"\\#{$unicode}\"";
```

I tried [this](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/RxZONd). Hope it helps.

Comment: your solution does not work when you are passing in the variable, which is the entire point of this question

Answer (score 0):

The nuances of the backslash behavior is an ongoing issue in Sass (e.g.,
 [libsass#1115](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1115)).

That being said, there are a few hacks provided in [sass#659](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/659), *but they are strongly dependent on the version and implementation of Sass*. The [solution provided by andrewgrewell](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/659#issuecomment-71759457) seemed to work well for many people but in any case see which solutions/hacks work for you. **[SassMeister Demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/cba117cd2119ed1f028f320e5f8ea8c8)**

```
@mixin after-font-awesome($unicode, $size, $margin, $color, $weight) {
  &:after {
    content: #{"\"\\"}#{$unicode + "\""}; // <-- andrewgrewell's hack
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: $size;
    color: $color;
    font-weight: $weight;
    margin: $margin;
    @content;
  }
}

// Usage
.selector {
  @include after-font-awesome('f078', 15px, 0 0 0 0.3em, orange, 900);
}

// CSS Output
.selector:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: orange;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.3em;
}
```